# Connect GIMP with PHP or Python

Tags: php, python, gimp

is there any way to connect GIMP with python or PHP and use its libraries? It seems that all i can find on the web is pygimp which is not supported anymore.

ps. i do my development on mac and i use linux as a production server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write GIMP plugins in Python (see, for example [James Hestenridge's clothify](http://www.jamesh.id.au/software/pygimp/), then call the plug-in from the command-line with a command of the form

```
gimp -i -b '(python-fu-bw-film RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "/path/to/filename.jpg" 0 1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE)' -b '(gimp-quit 0)'
```

It's not exactly pretty, but it's possible. Here is [another example](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=5948138&postcount=4).

Comment: Haven't tried this yet but thank you so much! I think it's enough to get my hand dirty

Answer (score 1):

Probably not directly, but I'll bet you can access some functions via 'exec()' on the command line.  What are you trying to do?  Can the GD or ImageMagic tools help?

Comment: Hi & thnx for the answer. The eternal problem, i'm trying to access some psd's layer information. I'm mostly interested in layer's position. I mean i know i can trim or convert a layer but i want its position also, relatively to the other layers

Answer (score 1):

One important thing regarding running gimp python plugin in batch mode.
Option -i means no interface. But in gimp documentation there is another option with same explanation --no-interface. User could though that they have same effect.
But when you try to run batch script on remote linux machine, with option -i you will get 'no display'. With option --no-interface, batch script will run without error. My colleague discovered that this is undocumented gimp 2.6.11 feature.

Regards, Karlo.