# Start Gimp plug-in at start-up

Tags: python, plugins, blender, gimp, python-fu

I'm trying to create a Blender add-on that syncs it with Gimp. So, I have a python-fu plug-in for Gimp and I want to achieve this: when I open Gimp from Blender(with Python), Gimp should run this plug-in immediately(at start-up)! But, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sort of duplicate of: [How to use GIMP inside a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196210/how-to-use-gimp-inside-a-python-script) (at least the accepted answer also answers this question).

The following article may also be helpful: [Python-Fu #4 - Using Python-Fu in Gimp Batch Mode](http://www.exp-media.com/content/extending-gimp-python-python-fu-plugins-part-4).

Comment: Well, it worked with this: cmd = " (python-fu-bgsync RUN-NONINTERACTIVE)"; subprocess.Popen(['gimp', '-b', cmd])... Really strange, you register it like this(python_fu) and you call it like this(python-fu)... WTF? Anyway, thanks!!!